# “Buddy cop show” without two cops?

Tags: trope, genre

"Buddy cop show" is a common trope; but so is a partnering of a cop and a civilian, and especially a cop and an extraordinary civilian (a mentalist in The Mentalist, an immortal in Forever, a fallen angel in Lucifer, a blocked writer in Castle, a tattooed amnesiac in Blindspot, a mnemophage in iZombie, etc.). Is there a common name for this trope? If not, what would be a succinct way to describe it?

Originally posted [to English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310995/buddy-cop-show-without-two-cops). Cop and Scientist from TVTropes was proposed and seems to awkwardly fit, but in many of these the partner is not a scientist (Mentalist, Lucifer, Blindspot, Castle), or is not primarily used for the scientific expertise (iZombie).

Comment: Odd couple comes to mind

Comment: [Take your pick](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DuoTropes)

Comment: Doesn't that made it into cross post?

Comment: I think the term is 'not based in reality.'

Comment: @ankit the response on english.se was to direct them here. It should of just been migrated, but since it's dont, the english.se one should be deleted or closed.

Comment: _Mnemophage_. I learn something new on this site every day.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong: Eh, I just made it up (but I believe it is well-formed). Maybe Latin "memorivore" might be more recognisable than Greek? :)

Comment: @Amadan I was aware that it's a made up word and my comment was tongue-in-cheek. That said, I really like the word :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TV Trope for this is called [**They Fight Crime**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheyFightCrime), basically any time two dissimilar people team up to fight crime. 90% of the time, it's a straight man, by the book cop and a funny man unconventional non-cop, but not always. It often employs the [**double act**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_act) (aka comedic duo) even when it's not a comedy. Even when it's a gritty no-fun-allowed drama. Then it's called bad cop/good cop. Semantics really.

All those shows genre wise would be a ***[procedural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_(genre)#Fiction)***. That's the general term for them. Even as a police procedural, because it all boils down to most of the mentioned shows being about crime solving in a semi legal way. Ratings and reviews wouldn't care about the specifics of the characters non-police job title is.

Comment: Thank you, I believe that's as good as I'm going to get.